# Is there any magnetic resonance spectroscopy that based on orbital angular momentum?

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, nmr-spectroscopy, epr-spectroscopy

The different momenta of electron and nucleus are described by different quantum numbers.

(a) *l* and *m$_l$* describe the **orbital** angular momentum and quantization on its component along an arbitrary direction, respectively.

(b) *s* and *m$_s$* describe the **electron spin** angular momentum and quantization on its component along an arbitrary direction, respectively.

(c) *I* and *m$_I$* describe the **nuclear spin** angular momentum and quantization on its component along an arbitrary direction, respectively.

Those space quantizations can be exploited for spectroscopy. For example, *m$_I$* $\implies$ the direction of nuclear spin angular momentum w.r.t. external magnetic field is quantized $\implies$ when magnetic field applied, because of the multiple possible directions w.r.t. external field, the energy of initially degenerate states will split according to the direction of angular momentum (i.e. according to the value of $m_I$), and the gaps between the now non-degenerate states can be probed by spectroscopy, and that gives structural information.

magnetic resonance spectroscopy based on $m_I$ = NMR

magnetic resonance spectroscopy based on $m_s$ = EPR

Is there any kind of similar magnetic resonance spectroscopy based on $m_l$? When an external magnetic field is applied, won't the energy of electron also split according to $m_l$? But I do not recall any spectroscopic method based on $m_l$.

Comment: You might look into the Zeeman and Paschen-Back effects https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeeman_effect

Comment: I think Zeeman effect cannot be considered as "pure" $m_l$, because Zeeman effect led to the concept of electron spin.

Comment: @M.Farooq Indeed! These were just the first things that came to mind, and I hoped they might nudge someone towards what might be an answer

Comment: @Ian Bush, What about Stark effect? Basically, I think the OP wanted to see how $m_l$ is experimentally detected. Interesting question.

Comment: @M.Farooq I almost mentioned the Stark effect, but didn't because of the OP's focus on magnetism. But it's certainly very closely related.

Comment: @IanBush, Right, I think there is no magnetic spectroscopy analogue for detecting $m_l$.

Comment: @M.Farooq Is there any known reason why is that so? Certainly, $m_l$ does express some kind of space quantization, and so seems like that could be exploited for spectroscopy.

Comment: @TheLearner, I may be wrrong but there is no magnetic moment associated with orbital motion. The $m_l$ values become observable in Stark experiments. I will try to modify your question properly and ask it in SE physics.

Comment: @M.Farooq: there is actually a magnetic moment associated with orbital angular momentum. Classically this is easy to picture as a moving charge generates a magnetic field that can interact with the external field. This interaction is however roughly a factor of two smaller than the interaction of the electron spin with the external magnetic field (compare their respective $g$ factors). In a strong magnetic field, orbital and electron spin angular momentum decouple from each other and recouple to the external field axis. This should be observable with EPR-like techniques.